# svn+ssh:// works, but not svn://

Tags: linux, svn, svnserve

I'm running svnserve on a server, but I can only access it with the svn+ssh protocol, not svn. (This appears to present a problem when I try to checkout from it with Capistrano.) Can anyone point out what might be wrong?

**Svn's machine:**

```
[root@machine ~]# service svnserve status
svnserve (pid  13166) is running...
```

**Local machine:**

```
$ svn info svn+ssh://root@<svnserver>.com/svnrepos/myrepo
-- returns fine
$ svn info svn://<svnserver>.com/svnrepos/myrepo
svn: E170001: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://<svnserver>.com/svnrepos/myrepo'
svn: E170001: No access allowed to this repository
```

I have even tried making use of the `--username` and `--password` params but have had exactly the same results.

### UPDATE:

To set up Subversion, I followed the brief instructions to [Setup a Subversion Server in 4 Minutes](http://www.tonyspencer.com/2007/03/02/setup-a-subversion-server-in-4-minutes/). My only deviation from its instructions was to kill the daemon svnserve process after I found it wasn't working for the `svn://` protocol and then use `service` to start svnserve. (It likewise didn't work.)

Comment: Did you check [this topic](http://www.svnforum.org/threads/34792-Problem-with-config-No-access-allowed-to-this-repository) already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your question would be easier if you provide :

- What you have done so far to make it work (eg set up svnserve, ...)
- OS version.

Therefore, I'll make the following assumption :

- Nothing has been done so far to make svnserve works
- You are using RHEL (service status).

Here's an untested setup (from memory and man pages):

- Edit /etc/sysconfig/svnserve

```
OPTIONS="--threads --root /path/to/svnroot"
```

- Edit /path/to/svnroot/conf/svnserve.conf

```
[general]
anon-access = none
auth-access = read
password-db = passwd
realm = My First Repository
```

- Edit /path/to/svnroot/conf/passwd

```
[users]
joeuser = joepassword
jayrandom = randomjay
```

- Refer to [man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/5/svnserve.conf) for further information

Comment: Thank you much, sir. My failing was to set `password-db` in my svnserve.conf file. I actually have no file at /etc/sysconfig/svnserve, but one turns up at /etc/rc.d/init.d/svnserve. Might this file serve the same function?

Comment: As I still don't know about your distro, it's hard to guess